# calling java functions to invoke health state of weblogic using Timer

Tags: java, jmx

I have created function to invoke health parameters of weblogic using JMX. functions are called using object in main class. Running as an application is giving me output. But I need to call those functions every 5 minutes and running through timer task is giving me an error of unsupported protocol t3. Here is the code..`ServletHealthStateMonitor` is the class where main method is there.

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {

    Timer time = new Timer(); 
    TimerTask hourlyTask = new TimerTask () {

        @Override
        public void run() {


             String[] args={};
            try {
                ServerHealthStateMonitor.main(args);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    time.schedule(hourlyTask, 0, 5*60*1000);
}
```

Comment: Check out this URL: http://gerardnico.com/wiki/weblogic/t3

Comment: I have already added wljmxclient.jar in my classpath..It is giving me correct output when i run it alone..but when i schedule it then it is giving me error.